# Macで共有したフォルダをUbuntu でマウントするにはどうすればいいですか

Tags: ubuntu

> sudo mount -t cifs -o username=name,sec=ntlm //pass/共有したフォルダ /mnt/samba

というコマンドを打ったのですがうまくいきませんでした。
Windowsから共有した場合はうまくいきました。
マウントできている方教えていただけると助かります。

Comment: ずいぶん前のスレですが、[このようなアプローチ](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1887568&s=0568cb3a65bca31a293175a40d6d1a5e&p=11509307#post11509307)はどうですか。あと、ご注意くださいー、あのスレでは最初のコマンドの内容には「crednetials」ではなく、「credentials」の方が正しい言葉だと思います。お役に立つかどうか分かりませんが・・・

Comment: @summea コメントありがとうございます。できるかどうかわかりませんが試してみます。

Comment: 「うまくいきませんでした」ではなく、なぜうまくいかないと判断したのか(エラーが出たとか、こうなって欲しいが実際にはこうなったとか)を具体的に書きましょう。

Answer (score 2):

[Apple Support Communitiesのスレッド](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3196311?start=30&tstart=0) によると `nounix,sec=ntlmssp` オプションが必用だそうです。試してみてください。

（例）
`mount.cifs //192.168.xxx.xxx/test /mnt/test/ -o user=******,password=******,nounix,sec=ntlmssp`